# SVN browse and adminstration?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, svn

I'm looking for a locally installable Apache webapp that will act as a frontend to local SVN repos for browsing and administration. Specifically I need:

- Access controls based on the SVN repo's authz, and passwd
- Administrative functions, like adding users, changing access controls
- Statistics, to monitor the use of the server

A some features would be allowing trusted users to add post commit hooks and a log oriented view (as an admin, I don't care so much about the code as seeing the history).

Answer (score 2):

for first one, and only partially - [websvn](http://www.websvn.info/) can understand authz file and follow access rules you define there.

for adding users - consider using ldap as more general authentication mechanism, and use it for authenticating when accessing svn. i'm using ms active directory and have http-based auth for svn server [ and websvn ], i have reasonable defaults for all authenticated users and give more rights only for those who need them, where they need them.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to check out [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). There are Ubuntu packages and it'll do what you need, plus more.

Comment: I've always assumed Trac was an issue tracker, which I don't need in this case. I now worry if I pull out Trac, I'll get sucked into mission creep.